# how to round up a double value in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there anyway to round up a double value?

I want result always rounded up.

```
int offSet = (totalRecords / 10).round();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's [`ceil`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/double/ceil.html):

> Returns the least integer no smaller than this.

```
int offSet = (totalRecords / 10).ceil();
```

Answer (score -2):

Here I'm rounding it to the next double or to next 0.5;
Sample: If its 6.6 then rount to 7.0. If its 6.2, then round to 6.5. See code bellow:

```
String arredonde(String n) {
final List x = n.split('.'); //break in to a list
if (x.length > 1) { //if its 0, then its already a rounded number or integer
  int fstNmbr = int.parse(x[0]);
  final int lstNmbrs = int.parse(x[1]);
  if (lstNmbrs > 5) {
    fstNmbr = fstNmbr + 1;
    final String finalNumber = fstNmbr.toStringAsFixed(1);
    return finalNumber;
  } else {
    if (lstNmbrs != 0) {
      final double finalNumber = fstNmbr + 0.5;
      return finalNumber.toStringAsFixed(1);
    } else {
      return n;
    }
  }
} else {
  return n;
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try with

```
num.parse((totalRecords / 10).toStringAsFixed(3))
```

if you want 3 decimal

Comment: They want an `int`, not `String`.

Comment: There is no sense in needless string conversions for something which can be handled perfectly using numerical types and simple function calls.

Answer (score -3):

Now you have something like you want. I choose sup to 5 to round up, you can change if you want

```
num offSet = (totalRecords / 10);
var eval = offSet.toStringAsFixed(1).split('.');
var res =
    int.parse(eval[1]) > 5 ? int.parse(eval[0]) + 1 : int.parse(eval[0]);
print(res);
```